# How many different throws are there of $2$ red, $3$ blue and $4$ green dice?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many different throws are there of $2$ red, $3$ blue and $4$ green dice? All dice are thrown at once, and we do not distinguish between dice of the same color.

Comment: Are the dice all 6-sided?

Comment: dice are always 6 sided in a Q unless they tell you, a bit like a coin is going to have two sides, not a mobius strip or anything - unless they tell you otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_i$ represent the number of dice that are equal to $i$, where $1\le i\le 6$.

The number of possibilities for the red dice is the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_6=2$ where $x_i\ge0$,

the number of possibilities for the blue dice is the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_6=3$ where $x_i\ge0$,

and the number of choices for the green dice is the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots +x_6=4$ where $x_i\ge 0$.

Using stars and bars, the number of possible throws is $\dbinom{7}{2}\dbinom{8}{3}\dbinom{9}{4}=148,176$.

Answer (score 0):

it's like the 'how many ways can I choose apples, bananas and oranges to make up 10 fruit?  where the answer can be generated from combining 2 partitions and 10 choices e.g. FFXFFFFFXFFF - so each block of F's is apples, bananas then oranges (2, 5 and 3 respectively)

This one is 5 partitions and n (no dice) choices

so for 2 dice it is

C(7,2) = 21

C(7,2) x C(8,3) x C(9, 4) = 148176

note

DDXXXXX

move all the D's around in the X's - then the first partition is 1's then the second partition is 2's

so DDXXXXX is 2x1's and zero of everyting else

DXXXXDX is 1 x 1 and 1 x 5 etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are all 6 sided dice, lets consider each colour separately. For the red dice, there are 36 possible configurations, but only the doubles are unique. The others can be swapped, so have a sister configuration. Hence there are 30/2+6=21 different throws of the red dice.

The rest is similar, and is basically an application of the orbit stabilizer theorem.

Blue Dice; configurations:
Triples:6
Doubles:6x6=36
All different:6x5x4=120

symmetries:
Triples: 1
Doubles: 3
All different: 6

Throws= 6/1+36/3+120/6=6+12+20=38

If we do a similar calculation for the green dice, and multiply these values together, we get the the total possible unique throws

Comment: for 3 dice you've got 6 trebles - you've got 6 different doubles, each with one of 5 singles = 30 - you have got the 20 3 x singles = 56 in total = C(8, 3) = 8! / 5! /3!